# Change whole <li> color on hover, not just href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the whole background-color of the li on hover. I have looked at other examples on Google and Stackoverflow, but I think there may be something conflicting in my code.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uDNn/)

HTML:

```
<div id="nav_bar">
       <div id="nav_bar_inside">
            <div class="nav_bar_content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a>Music</a></li>
                    <li><a>Pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a>Links</a></li>
                    <li><a>Biography</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .nav_bar {
        -webkit-animation:leftBar 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        float: left;
        background: #666;
        position:fixed;
        z-index: 15;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.75);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.75);
}    
#nav_bar #nav_bar_inside li {
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#nav_bar #nav_bar)inside a {display: inline-block;}
#nav_bar #nav_bar_inside li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: You could target it via `li:hover a` and just `li:hover`?

Comment: It would probably be more useful to simply make the `a` `display:block` and take up the entire `li`. Otherwise, it would indicate to the user they're hovering over a hit-area when they're not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach has the added benefit of making the entire LI clickable:

```
li {padding: 0;}
li a {display: block;}
```

Thanks to canon for the fiddle. Here it is tidied up:

http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/35gNz/4

Comment: This is really the only answer that makes sense. `a` is what you click... no sense lighting up the whole `li` and not making the link simply take up the entire `li`.

Comment: When you click above or below the link, it does not take you to the page.. Here is the updated fiddle reflecting what you said. http://jsfiddle.net/35gNz/1/ @isherwood

Comment: @PixelReaper you didn't remove the `padding` from the `li` (as prescribed). Move the `padding` (as well as the `height`) into the `a` definition. [Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/35gNz/2/).

Comment: Man @canon, you should just submit your own answer and I except it.. lol

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
#nav_bar #nav_bar_inside li a:hover
```

Should be:

```
#nav_bar #nav_bar_inside li:hover
```

Comment: This did it.. Completely over looked that.. Thank you! @FastTrack

Comment: 7 minutes until I can except it @FastTrack

Comment: @canon, that is not what I wanted to do. This is a simpler solution, and it is exactly what I was looking for. The a: takes up the whole li.

Comment: @FastTrack The whole li does not link.. Can you update yours so the whole li link? Here is an updated fiddle with what a previous post advised, although, it does not link the whole li either. http://jsfiddle.net/35gNz/1/

Comment: My mistake @canon--I was being naive and didn't test that functionality fully. Although, isherwoods awnser also does not link with the full li.. Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/35gNz/1/

Answer (score 0):

:hover on the entire li - here's a mod of yours:

http://jsfiddle.net/hmfuL/

```
#nav_bar #nav_bar_inside li:hover {
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This is what fixed it, but their was a prior post that beat you to it.. Thanks anyways dude! @DavidC